# Improving the perception of load time in an angular2 app with systemjs

Tags: angular

I am using `angular2` with `system.js`.

We are noticing a pretty significant delay as the page is loading dependencies at startup. The app isn't even that complex yet so we are starting to think of ways to improve the load time, or to organize and change the way the startup happens if necessary.

Its not actually strictly important to improve the load time as much as it is important to improve the perception of the load time. Meaning if I can improve the time it takes to load the first component while the rest of the app continues loading in the background that would be perfectly acceptable.

However, I haven't seen a clear way to do this. Any suggestions would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Angular Universal could achieve just that.

My understanding is that it renders the application quickly server side, until the client javaScript is ready to take over.

Found on [universal.angular.io](https://universal.angular.io/):

> First time users of your application will instantly see a server rendered view which greatly improves perceived performance and the overall user experience. According to research at Google, the difference of just 200 milliseconds in page load performance has an impact on user behavior.

If you need to improve perceived load time, it seems the way to go - if you are running a server.